# How to configure dhcpd to register ipv4 with bind while having static ipv6 addresses?

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, bind, ipv4

I have IPv6 configured on my local network via `radvd`; it advertises a routable IPv6 block, that all the machines auto-configure.s

I have IPv4 assigned to a NAT'd block via dhcpd and that updates named.

My problem is that when I set the AAAA record for a host for it's IPv6 address (which doesn't change), named will then start rejecting name updates from dhcpd for the A record.

named reports the following error:

```
'name not in use' prerequisite not satisfied (YXDOMAIN)
```

dhcpd will report the following error:

```
Has an A record but no DHCID, not mine
```

How can I either convince dhcpd to ignore the `AAAA` record when doing the named update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/IA64wiki/IPv6DDNS

Essentially dhcpd has a way to add hooks for events, so on a IPv4 registration call a script that will generate the standard MAC based IPv6 address and register that.

**UPDATE:**
(I'm using ICH DHCP 4.1)

When using the "on commit" hook, it removes the existing dynamic update so you need to copy that into your "on commit" section, mine now looks like this:

```
on commit {
    if (not static) {
        # Setup IPv6 Address
        set new-ddns-fwd-name = pick-first-value(ddns-hostname, host-decl-name);
        if (exists host-name and option host-name ~~ "^[a-z0-9.-]+$") {
                set new-ddns-fwd-name = option host-name;
        } elsif (exists dhcp-client-identifier and option dhcp-client-identifier ~~ "^[a-z0-9.-]+$") {
                set new-ddns-fwd-name = substring(option dhcp-client-identifier, 1, 50);
        } elsif (new-ddns-fwd-name = "") {
                set new-ddns-fwd-name = binary-to-ascii (16, 8, "-",
                                 substring (hardware, 1, 6));
        }
        set ddns-fwd-name = new-ddns-fwd-name;
        execute ("/opt/bin/ddns-ipv6", ddns-fwd-name, ucase(
                binary-to-ascii(16, 8, ":", substring(hardware, 1, 6))),
                binary-to-ascii(10, 8, ".", leased-address));
        unset new-ddns-fwd-name;

        switch (ns-update (not exists (IN, A, ddns-fwd-name, null),
                           add (IN, A, ddns-fwd-name, leased-address,
                                lease-time / 2))) {
        default:
            unset ddns-fwd-name;
            break;

        case NOERROR:
            set ddns-rev-name =
                concat (binary-to-ascii (10, 8, ".", reverse (1, leased-address)), ".", 
                        pick (config-option server.ddns-rev-domainname,
                              "in-addr.arpa."));

            switch (ns-update (delete (IN, PTR, ddns-rev-name, null),
                               add (IN, PTR, ddns-rev-name, ddns-fwd-name, lease-time / 2)))
            {
            default:
                unset ddns-rev-name;
                on release or expiry {
                    execute ("/opt/bin/ddns-ipv6", "-d",  pick-first-value(ddns-hostname, host-decl-name));
                    switch (ns-update (delete (IN, A, ddns-fwd-name,
                                           leased-address))) {
                    case NOERROR:
                       unset ddns-fwd-name;
                       break;
                    }
                    on release or expiry;
                }
                break;

            case NOERROR:
                on release or expiry {
                    execute ("/opt/bin/ddns-ipv6", "-d",  pick-first-value(ddns-hostname, host-decl-name));
                    switch (ns-update (delete (IN, PTR, ddns-rev-name, null))) {
                    case NOERROR:
                        unset ddns-rev-name;
                        break;
                    }
                    switch (ns-update (delete (IN, A, ddns-fwd-name,
                                           leased-address))) {
                    case NOERROR:
                        unset ddns-fwd-name;
                        break;
                    }
                    on release or expiry;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the folllowing line to `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`:

```
update-conflict-detection false;
```

Comment: Such short answers are often not terribly helpful. Consider expanding your post with an explanation of your suggestion or documentation that supports your solution.